# How to change MessageBox text content

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

Currently i have a MessageBox.Show call declared like that:

```
MessageBox.Show("Foo missing in configuration","Configuration Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

What i would like to accomplish is to change the content of the text dynamically. So what i did is the following:

```
MessageBox.Show("Foo" + fooName + " missing  in configuration","Configuration Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

Where fooName value is set before.

Im just wondering if there is a way to do it like:

```
MessageBox.Show("Foo {0} missing in configuration", fooName, "Configuration Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

Its not a big problem. For me it just looks/feels better if it would work like in the last proposal.

Maybe somebody knows a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not with the `MessageBox` methods themselves. But you can always use `string.Format()`

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Foo {0} missing in configuration", fooName),
    "Configuration Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

If you're looking for something a little more convenient, you can always define your own method:

```
public static void ShowMessageBox(string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, string format, params object[] formatArgs)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format(format, formatArgs), caption, buttons, icon);
}
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
ShowMessageBox("Configuration Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
    MessageBoxIcon.Error, "Foo {0} missing in configuration", fooName);
```

(Note: I rearranged the parameters a bit; the `params` of course has to be last, and putting the format just before them keeps the related arguments together).

Comment: Great answer. Just in case anyone was wondering, you can't create an extension method to the `MessageBox` class because it has no public constructors, so defining your own custom method in a wrapper class as shown here is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Format` method of the `string` class you can easily accomplish this in two lines:

```
string msg = string.Format("Foo {0} missing in configuration", fooName);
MessageBox.Show(msg,
    "Configuration Error", 
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
    MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

or in one longer (and in my opinion uglier) line:

```
MessageBox.Show( string.Format("Foo {0} missing in configuration", fooName),
    "Configuration Error", 
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
    MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```